# SQL: Flag when a user has a status of approved or denied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building a dashboard to track how many people have been approved/denied and need to create a view to flag when someone has a status of 'approved' or one of many status that maps to 'denied'. The data looks something like this.

| person_id | status | status_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | In Progress | 5/1/22 |
| 1 | Sent | 5/2/22 |
| 2 | In Progress | 5/1/22 |
| 3 | Sent | 5/2/22 |
| 3 | Denied | 5/3/22 |
| 3 | Appealed | 5/4/22 |
| 3 | Approved | 5/5/22 |
| 4 | Sent | 5/4/22 |
| 4 | Administrative Denial | 5/5/22 |

I want to create a view that outputs something like this where there is one row per id and flags for whether the user has a status of approved and/or denied

| person_id | approved | denied |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |

Comment: RE: <<< ... or one of many status that maps to 'denied'. >>> How do we recognize them? Will they all contain "denied" as a sub-string?

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is called **conditional aggregation**:

```
SELECT person_id
    , MAX(CASE WHEN status='Approved' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As approved
    , MAX(CASE WHEN status IN ('Denied', 'Administrative Denial', 'etc') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as denied
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY person_id
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd1f55b01c437cdbfa40507dd14ede4a

If would be better to have the status values in a table we could JOIN to, where the approved/denied result was one of the columns.

Comment: Why `MAX`? You can get only 1 or 0, no matters if multiple approved and denied status per user

Comment: @Alexey Why not? You could also use `COUNT()` and change the `ELSE` to `NULL` instead of `0` and get these results (`SUM()` does *not* work here), but I prefer this over trusting the database isn't set for weird NULL handling.